# What is the pyplot synonym for ax.get_xaxis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

I am trying to use `ax.get_xaxis` for a logarithmic plot but I don't have axes. Instead I want to use a similar `matplotlib.pyplot` function to just use it on the current plot but I can't seem to find it online. What would it be?

Example:

```
plt.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

Comment: `ax = plt.gca()` is one of the most basic principles when it comes to working with pyplot.

Comment: So I am forced to use `axes` objects to use above function?

Comment: Yes. `get_xaxis()` is a method of the axes object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax = plt.gca() # get current axis
```

Now you have the axis.

(you can use similar logic with `plt.gcf()` to get the current figure)

Comment: That was not the question. I know that I can create axes.

Comment: This code does not create any axes. If finds the active axis and saves its reference to the variable ax, so that you can use methods on it.

You could have at least tried before saying it's not what you want.

Comment: It seems that you know more than me about python. Thank you sir